# Does Xamarin support iPad and iTouch development on a windows machine without a mac?

Tags: c#, ipad, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am a WPF C# .net developer and was delighted to hear about Xamarin.  So I went to their website, downloaded the free version of their app, and wanted to write an ios (iPad) app.  However, when I open a new project with the Xamarin IDE, it doesn't give me any option for and IOS project.  It's all android.

I went to their website and was watching one of their instructional videos on how to develop an IOS app, and they said you need to use a mac.  Was the video out of date, or do you really need to use a mac in order to use Xamarin to develop an iPad app?

If anybody has been using Xamarin, please pipe in here and let me know how this works and what the learning curve is to develop iPad apps using Xamarin.

Do I perhaps need to purchase the $1800 version of it, or can you do it with the free version?

Thanks for your help,
Curtis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you MUST have a Mac to do iOS development.  The Apple SDKs are only available on a Mac.  You can use a Mac as your primary dev machine, or you can develop in Windows with Visual Studio, and only use the Mac as a build server.

Answer (score 2):

If you buy the Business edition of Xamarin then you only need a Mac during a build which you can hire by the hour at http://www.macincloud.com/
With the business edition you can use Visual Studio (Express eiditions does not support any plugins so can not be used with Xamarin) on a Windows machine to write iOS apps.

Comment: I don't know about you, but I had **horrible** service with macincloud. The connections were crappy, the lack of customizing or changing the mac in any way was annoying, and they continued to bill us after cancelling. They also wouldn't respond to emails, only complaints on twitter.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the video is out of date.

You can use Visual Studio but to compile a native app or run an iOS simulator you need a Mac. The reason is that Apple SDK and their products - compiler, Xcode and the device simulator are needed in iOS development and they don't run on Windows

Comment: Visual Studio does not have to be in a VM, it can be on a separate machine

Comment: @Jason thanks, Jason. I had only seen in as VM but I guess it's just networking-fu.

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin Studio on Windows does not support Xamarin.iOS. You either need Visual Studio on Windows or Xamarin Studio on Mac.

The learning curve for iPad apps will be roughly the same as if you weren't using Xamarin in the sense that you still have to learn the iOS SDK, the platform, how the program is structured, where to put method calls... The main difference is do you want to use obj-C or C# and do you want to have any code re-use.

You don't need the $1800 version, but you do need the $999 version if you want to use Visual Studio. The starter has an app size restriction, so indie might be the most cost-effective if you do not need Visual Studio integration.